# Remove randomly generated class and id in with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the class and id in the website using only Javascript. But that site's class and id contains random numbers and random characters, which looks like this:

```
<body class="class-abc ahwk-1726-rand_banner-lauwj-5210 other-class">
    <div id="fire-id 3762-kahm-rand-banner_9728-jege other-id">
   ...
```

The common point of these classes and ids are in the form `(some digits or characters)(- or _)banner(- or _)(some numbers or characters)`.

With CSS, I can easily select them using the CSS Selector: `[class*="banner" i]` and `[id*="banner" i]`.

However, with the `remove()` in javascript it does not support CSS Selector.

So, how do I remove classes and ids of this form using Javascript?

Your answer will be highly appreciated!

Comment: `id` attributes with spaces [are invalid](http://www.html-5.com/attributes/id-attribute.html) in HTML.

Comment: What about `myElement.classList.remove(‘blah’)`?

Comment: @trincot That's not my website. Maybe the owner of that site has a purpose in doing so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are happy with the CSS selector, just iterate over the matches and delete them. But please note that it [is not valid HTML](http://www.html-5.com/attributes/id-attribute.html) when you have `id` attributes with spaces in them. An `id` attribute specifies *one* identifier, not a space-separated list of them.

So assuming that your HTML would be valid, you can do as follows:

```js
for (let elem of document.querySelectorAll('[id*="banner" i]')) {
    elem.removeAttribute("id");
}
for (let elem of document.querySelectorAll('[class*="banner" i]')) {
    elem.classList.remove(...elem.className.match(/\S+banner\S+/gi));
}

console.log(document.querySelector("div").outerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="class-abc ahwk-1726-rand_banner-lauwj-5210 other-class">
    <div id="fire-id">
    </div>
    <div id="3762-kahm-rand-banner_9728-jege">
    </div>
    <div id="other-id">
    </div>
</div>
```

So for `id` attributes we may assume that the `id` attribute can be removed. For `class` attributes we can search the value for the match(es) using a regular expression, and then pass the matching list to the `classList.remove` method.

### Dealing with invalid HTML

If you really want to *change* the value of an *invalid* `id` property with spaces, then proceed as follows:

```js
for (let elem of document.querySelectorAll('[id*="banner" i]')) {
    elem.setAttribute("id", elem.getAttribute("id").replace(/\S+banner\S+/gi, "").replace("  ", " "));
}
for (let elem of document.querySelectorAll('[class*="banner" i]')) {
    elem.classList.remove(...elem.className.match(/\S+banner\S+/gi));
}

console.log(document.querySelector("div").outerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="class-abc ahwk-1726-rand_banner-lauwj-5210 other-class">
    <!-- invalid HTML follows... --->
    <div id="fire-id 3762-kahm-rand-banner_9728-jege other-id">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Added a section for dealing with those invalid `id` properties.

Comment: I am not the owner of that website, I think the owner of that website has set such id for some reason which I do not know myself. However, your removal of `class` worked fine. But removing the `id` you provided removed the entire `id` property, which caused a site layout error, and some of the DOM on that site didn't work after it was removed.

Comment: Did you see my edit? It addresses this point. The first part of my answer is intended for dealing with *valid* HTML, as I don't want to provide bad practices in my answer. But as you insist, I hesitantly added the alternative that accepts spaces in `id` attributes and updates them accordingly. Note that as this goes against the HTML specification there is no guarantee that this will work on all implementations of HTML/JavaScript agents.

Comment: Okay, after refreshing the page I saw your edits. It worked! Your answer has been accepted, thank you!
Sorry, I don't have enough 15 reputation for using "This answer is useful" yet, I will use it as soon as I have enough reputation.
Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove class or id from specific elements then find elements by tag name and remove class / id attrs like: element.removeAttribute('class') OR element.removeAttribute('id')

Comment: I don't want to remove the entire attribute, because by doing so, the website layout will be destroyed, aesthetically pleasing and may cause errors.